# Is double quote (") a preprocessing-token or an unterminated string literal?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, token, c-preprocessor, string-literals

Is double quote (`"`) a preprocessing-token or an unterminated string literal?

C11, 6.4 Lexical elements, Syntax, 1:

```
preprocessing-token:
    header-name
    identifier
    pp-number
    character-constant
    string-literal
    punctuator
    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
```

C11, 6.4.5 String literals, Syntax, 1:

```
string-literal:
    encoding-prefix(opt) " s-char-sequence(opt) "
```

Note: GCC considers it to be an unterminated string literal:

```
#if 0
"
#endif
```

produces:

```
warning: missing terminating " character
```

Comment: An unterminated string is just an error. A fully properly terminated string is a `preprocessing-token`.

Comment: “that cannot be one of the above” is probably intended to exclude `"`.

Comment: Are you trying to convert the C standard to some formal specification?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm trying to understand the required behavior in the example above. If `"` is an unterminated string literal, then `"` is not a _group_ (6.10 Preprocessing directives), because `"` is not a `preprocessing-token`. Hence, the `"` is not skipped (6.10.1 Conditional inclusion, Semantics, 6). Hence, a diagnostic "unterminated string literal" can be produced. Is that correct?

Comment: @EricPostpischil And it turns out that the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2018 6.4.1 3 says one category of preprocessing tokens is “single non-white-space characters that do not lexically match the other preprocessing token categories”, and the next sentence says “If a `’` or a `"` character matches the last category, the behavior is undefined.” Thus, if an isolated `"` appears (one that is not paired with another `"` with an *s-char-sequence* between them), it fails to match the lexical form of a string literal and is parsed as a single non-white-space character that does not match the other categories, and the behavior is not defined by the standard. This explains the GCC message.

(I note that 6.10.2 3 describes `#` `include` directives with “`"` *q-char-sequence* `"` *new-line*”. However, the earlier grammar in 6.10 1 describes the directives as “`#` `include` *pp-tokens* *new-line*”. My interpretation of this is that the directive is parsed as having preprocessor token(s), notably a string literal, and 6.10.2 3 says that if that string literal has the form shown as “`"` *q-char-sequence* `"`”, then it is a `#` `include` directive of the type that paragraph is discussing.)